# Rails Association putting a form_for in a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What I'm trying to do is be able to add notes and associate them with clients in Rails.

My client model looks like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_name, :contact_name, :email_address, :phone_number,
                                :street_address, :city, :state, :zip

  has_many :notes, dependent: :destroy

end
```

And my notes model looks like this:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :client
  default_scope order: 'notes.created_at DESC'

  validates :client_id, presence: true
end
```

My index.html.erb of my client looks like this:

```
<% @clients.each do |client| %>
   .
   .
   .
   <%= form_for(@notes) do |f| %>
                        <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new note..." %>
                        <%= f.submit "Add Note", class: "buttonPri addnote" %> 
                    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in my clients controller I have:

```
def index
    if signed_in?
        @clients = Client.all
  @note = client.notes.build
    else
        redirect_to signin_path
      end
end
```

and in my notes controller:

```
def create
    @note = client.notes.build(params[:note])
    if @note.save
      flash[:success] = "Note Created"
      redirect_to root_path
        else
      render 'static_pages/home'
      end
    end
```

I get `undefined local variable or method client for #<ClientsController:0x007f835191ed18>` error when I load the client index page. What I think is happening is that the controller can't see the block variable `client` and I need to move it out of the controller and into the form_for. Is that the right approach and how do I do that?

I was looking through the rails API and found this:

```
<%= form_for([@document, @comment]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
Where @document = Document.find(params[:id]) and @comment = Comment.new.
```

Is this the direction I need to go in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is you're referring to `client` in your controller but this isn't defined.

Based on your example:

```
def create
  @note = client.notes.build(params[:note])
  if @note.save
    flash[:success] = "Note Created"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end
```

Where is `client` supposed to be coming from? Usually it's loaded by a parent controller class in a `before_filter` call that typically looks like:

```
before_filter :load_client

def load_client
  @client = Client.find_by_id!(params[:client_id])
end
```

It could be you have a `client` method defined that is returning `nil` because it can't find something. In which case you should track that down and see what the problem is. This is where using `find!` which throws an exception instead of quietly failing is often a better way to go.

When you see errors relating to calling methods on `nil` it's a sign that something hasn't been loaded properly, so you should track down that missing object.

Comment: I want client to come out of the @clients each block as the block variable. But, I don't know if that is even possible. A load_client method wouldn't work because there are multiple clients on a single page and I need to know which client is associated with the new note.

Comment: The `client` variable defined in your view has nothing to do with your controller, they are two completely different contexts. In fact, the scope of that variable is usually *only* within the block in question. If you're submitting notes for multiple clients simultaneously you will need to handle this differently. The standard REST calls are for one object at a time.

Comment: Right, I only want to submit one at a time. It's sort of like twitter. I have a list of tweets (clients), but I could reply (add notes to any of them). How do I make sure I get the right reply with the right tweet?

Comment: It might be simpler to create a separate form for each client so that each can be routed to the appropriate `create` call. That's a more conventional approach.

Comment: is it possible I could pass the client from the each block via a link to a new controller that would then hit a create controller?

Comment: The only way to pass things from a view back to the controller is via your GET and POST parameters. Remember HTTP is stateless.